# Get all records from mysql database from a certain duration

Tags: mysql

I made a code to get all records from 5 minutes (fetch all comments) and my date in database is in UNIX timestamp. It seems to be not working . The query is

```
select comment_id,from_unixtime(a.date / 1000, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') from ai_shipment_comments a, ai_users b where a.parent_id = '26' or a.comment_id='26' and a.user_id=b.user_id AND a.date >= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE) * 1000 ORDER BY a.date ASC
```

The results are empty but it should return result

Comment: Have you checked that the calculation gives reasonable value for the time?

Comment: Yes i did. I but still no results

Comment: Why are you multiplying by *1000? You already have a timestamp.

Comment: Well without that also its not showing correct results